# QWidget окну задать родителя по HWND

Tags: c++, qt

Операционная система Windows. Qt 5.5.1
Написал средствами Qt библиотеку (DLL) в которой есть графический интерфейс.
Подключаю её к другому проекту. Есть hwnd родителя. Нужно окну которое показывает библиотека задать родителя по hwnd. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что написано в MSDN, это сейчас делается практически также как и для Windows 95:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, (LONG_PTR)hWndOwner);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QWindow *window = QWindow::fromWinId(hwnd);
QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
```

Comment: Этот способ делает обёртку QWidget вокруг окна с hwnd. Я пробовал обернуть родительское окно, чтобы потом привязаться к нему, но тогда родительское окно "портится": меняя размер окна, содержимое не растягивается, оно не перерисовывается и не реагирует на события мыши (может и на другие тоже)

Comment: Может делать наоборот - не создавать QWidget* родителя, а получить HWND дочернего виджета и использовать WinAPI функцию SetParent?

Comment: так я тоже делал, но winApi SetParen делает что-то типа MDI окна. Т.е. моё окно попадает внутрь родительского и не может покинуть его пределы. И вторая проблема: родитель назначается странно, т.к. при закрытии родителя, моё окно не закрывается и процесс продолжает висеть в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь понадобится метода `create QWidget`:

```
HWND main_window = WinID;
QWidget *w = new QWidget();
w->create((WinId)main_window);
```

Comment: Такое я нашёл, но не работает. В [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#create) написано: "The parameter window is ignored in Qt 5."

Comment: @Владимир а по документации пробовали сделать? Через `QWindow::fromWinId` и `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` ?

Comment: Да, но это делает обратную операцию. Этот способ оборачивает QWidget'ом виндовое окно с указанным hwnd. Я пробовал обернуть родителя и тогда получается успешно своему окну указать родителя . Но тогда родительское "ломается": перестаёт себя перерисовывать, не реагирует на события мыши, не изменяет размеры.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл способ который работает, правда сыпятся непонятные сообщения в консоль

```
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x24 (WM_GETMINMAXINFO), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x83 (WM_NCCALCSIZE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x5 (WM_SIZE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x3 (WM_MOVE), hwnd=0x0x110956.
setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+0+0 on QWindow/''. Resulting geometry:  640x480+-760+-370 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 640x480+0+0 on QWindow/''. Resulting geometry:  640x480+-760+-370 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
listLabels.size() 4
```

Пусть родительское окно это ownerWin, а дочернее QWidget-окно это childWin;

Если использовать SetWindowLongPtr, которую посоветовал oshatrk, то получается нужный эффект (дочернее окно всегда поверх родительского), но при закрытии родительского окна дочерний процесс продолжает висеть в памяти.

Чтобы привязать "сильнее" к родительскому, я создаю через WinApi ещё одно дочернее окно (middleWin) у которого родитель ownerWin. Делаю на него обёртку QWidget при помощи createWindowContainer(). После "оборачивания" оно "сломается", т.е. перестанет обрабатывать какие-либо события. Теперь к нему штатными средствами Qt можно привязать своё QWidget-окно. Получается три окна: родительское, промежуточное и моё. Закрываю middleWin функцией close(). Все эти действия делают так, что при закрывании ownerWin закрывается и childWin. А чтобы childWin было всегда поверх родительского использую SetWindowLongPtr, но её надо обязательно вызывать после функции show() дочернего окна, иначе она не работает.

Ниже функции которыми я пользуюсь. Вызывать сначала setWinParent(), затем showWindow(). В setWinParent() строки с 1 по 5 для меня "чёрный ящик", почему окно создаётся так - не знаю, где-то  нашёл в интернете.

```
void setWinParent(HWND ownerWin)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)this->winId();
    DWORD exStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) ;//1
    DWORD style   = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);//2
    WCHAR className[256];//3
    GetClassName(hwnd, className,256);//4
    HWND newHwnd = CreateWindowEx(exStyle, className, NULL, style,//5
                                  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                  ownerWin, NULL, qWinAppInst(), NULL);
    QWindow *qw=QWindow::fromWinId((WId)newHwnd);
    QWidget* qWidget = createWindowContainer(qw);
    qWidget->show();
    this->setParent(qWidget);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    qWidget->close();    
}
void showWindow(HWND ownerHwnd)
{
    show();
    SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)this->winId(), GWLP_HWNDPARENT, (LONG)ownerHwnd);
}
```